# animate roate3d css issue in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Hopefully someone can point out an obvious error, but I just can not get an image to animate 3drotate in Safari.

It works fine in Chrome.

```
.spinner
{

    animation: rotate360 6s infinite normal forwards linear;

}

@keyframes rotate360 
{
  0% 
  {

    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 0rad);    
  }
  50% 
  {

    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 3.05rad);    
  }
  100%
  {

    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 6.1rad);
  }

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Try adding a small delay before you animation starts, might be looking for a null dom element?

Comment: @DylanAnlezark How? In the css?

Comment: animation: rotate360 6s linear 0.01s infinite; - something like this

Comment: Another thing worth trying is to not use the shorthand notation when defining your animation